# How do I only trigger code when a QuickFix action is executed?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'd like to create a code action that either supplements a function with other functions or updates them, if already created. Whenever the Create-action is performed, the function is stored in a Cache, and if the function differs too much from the cached version, the Update-action becomes available.

However, I can't get the event after the execution of the code to trigger. As suggested here, I included a definition of the `resolveCodeAction` method of the `vscode.CodeActionProvider` class, but if doesn't actually get called.

Did I define the method wrong?

Here are relevant excerpts from my code.

```
export function activate(context: ExtensionContext) {
    context.subscriptions.push(
        languages.registerCodeActionsProvider('al',new EventSupplement(procedureCache),{
            providedCodeActionKinds: EventSupplement.providedCodeActionKinds
        })
    )
}
```

```
export class EventSupplement implements vscode.CodeActionProvider{
    public static readonly providedCodeActionKinds = [
        vscode.CodeActionKind.QuickFix
    ];

    provideCodeActions(
        document: vscode.TextDocument,
        range: vscode.Range | vscode.Selection,
        context: vscode.CodeActionContext,
        token: vscode.CancellationToken
    ): vscode.ProviderResult<(vscode.CodeAction | vscode.Command)[]> {
        let lineIndex = range.start.line;

        if(!StringUtil.IsLineValid(document,range))
            return;

        if(!StringUtil.ProcedureHasEvents(this.procedureCache[cacheIndex])){
            quickFixActions.push(this.AddEvents(cacheIndex));
        } else if(needsUpdate){
            quickFixActions.push(this.UpdateEvents(cacheIndex));
        }
        
        return quickFixActions;
    }

    resolveCodeAction(
        codeAction: vscode.CodeAction,
        token: vscode.CancellationToken
    ): vscode.ProviderResult<vscode.CodeAction> {
        if(codeAction.title == this.addActionTitle){
            if(typeof this.newProcedure == 'undefined')
                return(codeAction);
            this.eventCache.push(this.newProcedure);
        } else if(codeAction.title == this.updateActionTitle){
            if(typeof this.newProcedure == 'undefined')
                return(codeAction);
            let eventCacheIndex = ProcedureUtil.GetCacheIndexOfProcedure(this.newProcedure,this.eventCache);
            if(eventCacheIndex == -1)
                this.eventCache.push(this.newProcedure);
            else
                this.eventCache[eventCacheIndex] = this.newProcedure;
        }

        return(codeAction);
    }
}
```

```
private AddEvents(cacheIndex:number):vscode.CodeAction{
    let add = new vscode.CodeAction('Add Before- and After-Events',vscode.CodeActionKind.QuickFix);
    const procedure = this.procedureCache[cacheIndex];

    add.edit = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
    add.edit.replace(procedure.Document.uri,procedure.RangeAtStart,procedure.AddEvents());

    return(add);
}
```

Comment: the second argument of `registerCodeActionsProvider` is a function

Comment: @rioV8 It's not a function, it's a class that extends `vscode.CodeActionProvider'. I should have included it in the first place, I've edited the summary.

Comment: VSC interrogates all providers if after any code change there is a possible completion, it shows the lightbulb, and when the user presses `Ctrl+.` it shows the list to pick the action to take

Comment: I understand, but I want certain code to only execute when the user executed the code action. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: then fill in the `resolve` method of the provider

Comment: @rioV8 I tried defining the `resolveCodeAction` method, but it doesn't get called. Is it supposed to be somewhere else or is the definition wrong?

Comment: `resolveCodeAction` is called when the user selects a QuickAction, its parameter is the `CodeAction` that `provideCodeActions` has made and the user has selected

Comment: But then why isn't `resolveCodeAction` called in my case? I've tried setting a breakpoint in the method during debug, but the run was never interrupted, even after selecting an action.

Comment: then first try it with a hardcoded QuickAction

Comment: @rioV8 I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by hardcoded QuickAction.

Comment: `quickFixActions.push(new vscode.CodeAction('testing', vscode.CodeActionKind.QuickFix));`

Comment: @rioV8 I just tried that, and the code in `resolveCodeAction` still doesn't get called, even when executing the action.

Comment: there is a CodeAction sample extension, try that one

Comment: @rioV8 After setting `provideCodeAction` to public, executing the hardcoded function worked caused `resolveCodeAction` to finally trigger. However, the other actions still don't  trigger the event, even after also setting them from private to public.

Comment: try the JavaScript way, and look at the JavaScript generated by TypeScript, use an object with just a few methods defined

Comment: I did some testing and it seems that a code action won't be resolved as soon as its `edit` property is assigned to a new `vscode.Workspace` instance.